# div tags do not float properly in firefox, but work in safari and chrome - wordpress theme

Tags: css, wordpress, firefox, html, cross-browser

I've recently created a website via a modified wordpress theme. However on viewing the website yesterday in the office via the FIREFOX BROWSER I noticed the 3 x losenges 'soil labels' do not align properly in FIREFOX - but look ok in safari and chrome and display correctly (3 soil tags in 1 row), I've done some reading up on forums and tried a few solutions via using display: inline- block along with float: left and then I created a new CSS rules and assigned it to the far right soil tag with float; right and all have failed
to correct the FIREFOX display corrupting (i.e. middle soil tag losenge drops to the line below) - on viewing some forums last night I understand firefox can generate a few problems when using the float rule - any help would appreciated

link to website; http://creative-media.info/allotment/

the losenges referenced are the grey panels with triangle shaped bottoms 1. apply for a plot 2. shop and 3. gallery

Answer (score 0):

Padding and width for soiltagbutton is problem;

try

```
clear: both;
max-width: 40px;
min-height: 60px;
min-width: 107px;
padding: 1px 0 1px 80px;
position: relative;
```